# Package Manager Console not allowed to drop Index

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller, indexing, package-managers

I am trying to update my database to a new migration, but it gets stuck on a part where it needs to drop an index. It says: Cannot drop the index 'Player.IX_Player_OrganizationId1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

What I am doing is the following:

I open my package manager and run the command: add-migration [name]

Then I run the command: update-database

Then in proceeds to do some tings, altough its gets stuck on the command:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> DROP INDEX [IX_Player_OrganizationId1] ON [Player]; Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
> CommandTimeout='30'] DROP INDEX [IX_Player_OrganizationId1] ON
> [Player]; Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot
> drop the index 'Player.IX_Player_OrganizationId1', because it does not
> exist or you do not have permission.

So what i did was checking if the index is there, i did this with the sp_help player command in an SQL Query. This shows the following:

index_name
PK_Player
Player.IX_Player_OrganizationId1

So it does exist, which means i do not have permission to drop it. So then I runned the SQL query
Drop INDEX "Player.IX_Player_OrganizationId1"
on Player

Which did the job, but my data is not showing correctly in the web application (ASP.NET MVC)
I think this is because i didnt use a migration to update it, but i am not sure. Can anyone help me with either making sure the migration succeeds/giving the PM Console permissions or make sure the data shows correclty in my ASP.NET application.

Thank you in advance!

NOTE: using nuget.org package & Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packagaes

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem; I manually added the index using "indexname", where it should have been [indexname].